# Extraer decimal de una cadena

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda muy especifica para JavaScript:

Tengo la siguiente cadena:

```
var prueba ="Hola mundo 5.26"
```

Necesito extraer el numero decimal de esa cadena.
¿como se puede realizar esto?

Muchas Gracias

Comment: que has tratado?

Comment: Primer intento de búsqueda en google, Primer opción encontrada: [how-to-extract-decimal-number-from-string-using-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411833/how-to-extract-decimal-number-from-string-using-javascript). Hay que hacer el minino intento de antes de preguntar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con este expresión regular

```
var resultado = prueba.match(/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/g)
```

Comment: Manuel las respuestas con sólo código, sin explicar cómo se resuelve el problema, son consideradas malas respuestas. Aparte de eso, antes de responder quizá conviene que el OP indique lo que ha tratado o que  diga al menos que no tiene siquiera un punto de partida. En caso contrario se podría fomentar un estilo de sitio con preguntas del tipo: *hagan esto por mi*.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener el número dentro de un string de esta forma:

```
var prueba = "Hola mundo 5.26";
var numero = parseFloat(prueba.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g));
```

¡Suerte!